# classic asp replacing inside pre tag

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have like following text which get from html form. Now I want to save it into db. Before saving I need to parse for line break replacing with `<BR />` tag.

I only need to replace text outside of `<pre>` tag and leave text as it is inside of `<pre></pre>` tag.

This is what I currently have:

```
 strTxt="aaaaaaaaaaaa
    bbbbbbbbbbb
     <pre>
      sss ssss
      sss ddd
     </pre>
    asdafdsf
    sfsfsdf
     <pre>
      sfdsf
      sdfs
     </pre>
    asfasfsaf"
```

And I want the result to be:

```
strTxt="aaaaaaaaaaaa<br />
    bbbbbbbbbbb<br />
     <pre>
      sss ssss
      sss ddd
     </pre>
    asdafdsf<br />
    sfsfsdf<br />
     <pre>
      sfdsf
      sdfs
     </pre>
    asfasfsaf"
```

Comment: i am replacing line break like vbCrLf

Comment: yes actually, it is text from form (<textarea>) where user input text including <pre> tag and the text store variable strTxt.
I use replace function for line break (vbCrlf) but it it replaces in all text including <pre> tag, i only want to replace out side of <pre> tag

Comment: OK, is the code what you want it to look like? If so can you edit your question and add the original code as well.

Comment: Seems like a better title for your question would have been "How to replace vbCrLf in string except inside <pre> tag"

Comment: Regexp is not my cup of tea, but you could (i) change all vbCrLf inside the pre tag using regexp to a gibberish string, (ii) then just replace(full_string, vbCrLf, '<br>') and (iii) change the gibberish string inside the pre tag using replace(full_string, 'your_gibberish', vbCrLf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't use string operations when manipulating structured text like HTML, but `<pre>` is a special - not nested - case. So you can get away with:

```
Function BrNonPre(sAll)
  Dim csDelim : csDelim = "pre>" & vbCrLf
  Dim aAll    : aAll    = Split(sAll, csDelim)
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(aAll) Step 2
      aAll(i) = Replace(aAll(i), vbCrLf, "<br />" & vbCrLf)
  Next
  BrNonPre = Join(aAll, csDelim)
End Function
```

Sample output:

```
=======================
aaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbb
<pre>
  sss ssss
  sss ddd
</pre>
asdafdsf
sfsfsdf
<pre>
  sfdsf
  sdfs
</pre>
asfasfsaf
----------
aaaaaaaaaaaa<br />
bbbbbbbbbbb<br />
<pre>
  sss ssss
  sss ddd
</pre>
asdafdsf<br />
sfsfsdf<br />
<pre>
  sfdsf
  sdfs
</pre>
asfasfsaf
=======================
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hard code it like

```
 <%
 dim strTxt
 strTxt="aaaaaaaaaaaa<br />" & vbCrLf
 strTxt=strTxt & "bbbbbbbbbbb" & vbCrLf
 strTxt=strTxt & "<pre>" & vbCrLf
 strTxt=strTxt & "sss ssss" & vbCrLf
 strTxt=strTxt & "sss ddd" & vbCrLf
 strTxt=strTxt & "</pre>" & vbCrLf
 strTxt=strTxt & "asdafdsf<br />" & vbCrLf
 strTxt=strTxt & "sfsfsdf" & vbCrLf
 strTxt=strTxt & "<pre>" & vbCrLf
 strTxt=strTxt & "sfdsf" & vbCrLf
 strTxt=strTxt & "sdfs" & vbCrLf
 strTxt=strTxt & "</pre>" & vbCrLf
 strTxt=strTxt & "asfasfsaf"

 Response.Write(strTxt)
 %>
```

Comment: @mintokyo - I've shown you how to hard code what you want. As I'm still not totally sure what you want, I'm hoping this is OK?